# VirtueMart images filenames

Tags: virtuemart

I upgraded a Joomla 2.5 with VM 2.x to J3 and VM 3.x.

Everything was ok, but after I migrated the latest VM data just before put the new version to live, I am getting an issue with the VM media (images files).

Many the products won't show their images, although the images exist.
In VM Media Manager many media files don't have thumbnails. I renamed the resized folder, in order to force VM to recreated the thumbs, but VM reports:

> vmError: Couldnt create thumb, file not found

The problem I see, is that those images exist in the products images folder, but their names is of the type: P12001.JPG. For some reason VM cannot see these filenames. 
I also noticed that the same image files exist with the same name but in lowercase.

I don't know what might have happened and why the files exist twice both in upper/lower case and I don't know how it could work in previous versions.

Has anyone ever came across this kind of issue with VM?
Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any valuable answer for the question, apart that VM won't treat fine file-extensions in uppercase, like .JPG. 
So I ended up renaming all image filenames + file-extensions to lowercase and updated the file_url column medias database table of vm to lowercase as well.

Now everything works fine and there is a kind of consistency.